# Can one hide the Lat/Lng information sent to Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

most services that use google maps have the Longitude / Latitude stored in the source to be sent to google maps to render their markers.

However on this site (sorry Chinese)

http://www.dianping.com/shop/500451
I can't find this information for Latitude Longitude of their items. SO how does google know where they are supposed to render the marker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's encoded here: http://ditu.google.cn/maps?daddr=%e9%bb%84%e6%b5%a6%e5%8c%ba%e5%b9%bf%e4%b8%9c%e8%b7%af20%e5%8f%b7%e5%a4%96%e6%bb%a95%e5%8f%b7

I'd guess they are using an address instead of coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Using the example from underdark

if you - click the **分享链接 (link)** button it exposes the Latitude and Longitude

Long URL
http://ditu.google.cn/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=&daddr=&hl=zh-CN&geocode=&mra=mr&doflg=ptk&sll=**31.234723,121.491474**&sspn=0.011871,0.022724&brcurrent=3,0x35b270e5eeb60b11:0x9390f7d4e16ac67d,0,0x35ad8c73cd3952c7:0xbb190e9364c4e592%3B5,0,0&ie=UTF8&ll=**31.234723,121.491474**&spn=0.011871,0.022724&z=16

Comment: Cool, however this means that the longitude latitude never came from the original site. Just a string. (in other words it's only as precise as  google interprets it)